# About Spring Transaction Manager

Tags: spring, transactions

Currently i am using spring declarative transaction manager in my application. During DB operations if any constraint violated i want to check the error code against the database.  i mean i want to run one select query after the exception happened. So i am catching the DataIntegrityViolationException  inside my Catch block and then i am trying to execute one more error code query. But that query is not get executed . I am assuming since i am using the transaction manager if any exception happened the next query is not getting executed. Is that right?. i want to execute that error code query before i am returning the results to the client. Any way to do this?

```
@Override
@Transactional
    public LineOfBusinessResponse create(
        CreateLineOfBusiness createLineOfBusiness)
        throws GenericUpcException {
        logger.info("Start of createLineOfBusinessEntity()");


        LineOfBusinessEntity lineOfBusinessEntity =
            setLineOfBusinessEntityProperties(createLineOfBusiness);
        try {
            lineOfBusinessDao.create(lineOfBusinessEntity);
            return setUpcLineOfBusinessResponseProperties(lineOfBusinessEntity);

        }
        // Some db constraints is failed
        catch (DataIntegrityViolationException dav) {

            String errorMessage =
                errorCodesBd.findErrorCodeByErrorMessage(dav.getMessage());
            throw new GenericUpcException(errorMessage);
        }
        // General Exceptions handling
        catch (Exception exc) {
            logger.debug("<<<<Coming inside General >>>>");
            System.out.print("<<<<Coming inside General >>>>");
            throw new GenericUpcException(exc.getMessage());
        }

    }

public String findErrorCodeByErrorMessage(String errorMessage)throws GenericUpcException {
        try{
        int first=errorMessage.indexOf("[",errorMessage.indexOf("constraint"));
        int last=errorMessage.indexOf("]",first);
        String errorCode=errorMessage.substring(first+1, last);
        //return errorCodesDao.find(errorCode);
        return errorCode;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new GenericUpcException(e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think problem you're describing has anything to do with Transaction management. If `DataIntegrityViolationException` happens within your `try()` block you code within `catch()` should execute. Perhaps exception different from `DataIntegrityViolationException` happens or your `findErrorCodeByErrorMessage()` throwing another exception. In general, Transaction logic would be applied only once you return from your method call, until then you could do whatever you like using normal Java language constructs. I suggest you put breakpoint in your error error handler or some debug statements to see what's actually happening.

Comment: thank you for your reply. if i use @transaction annotation it's not even hitting catch block after exception comes. it is directly giving the error string from database.It's not allowing me to catch the error. if i dont use transaction annotation everything is working fine.And I am sure there is no problem in my findErrorCodeByErrorMessage() method . Anyway i posted my findErrorCodeByErrorMessage() method code.Please help me.